# Why is bootstrap form not submitting?

Tags: forms

I have a form like this with bootstrap

```
 <div class="container">
  <form>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-offset-3">
     <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
       <input type="text" class="form-control "  placeholder="Locate and get products/services ">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
     </span>
  </div><!-- /input-group -->
 </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
 </div>
</form>
</div>
```

When i hit the search submit button it does not submit but submits when i hit enter please what is wrong?

Comment: Forms need an action.

Comment: In addition to an `action` on your `<form>` element you probably want the `<button>` type to be `submit` rather than `button`.

Answer (score 2):

Make the button type to submit, add action to the form and add name to the button. U will either use the name or action to handle what you want your form to do. Your code doesn't detail what you need so if you fail to understand this try to edit your question and include the remaining code for help

```html
<div class="container" >
  <form action="put the page to go to">
   <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-offset-3" >
     <div class="input-group input-group-lg" >
       <input type = "text" class="form-control "  placeholder = "Locate and get products/services " >
      <span class="input-group-btn" >
       <button class="btn btn-default" name="products" type = "submit" > Search</button >
     </span >
  </div ><!-- /input - group-->
 </div ><!-- /.col - lg - 6-->
 </div >
</form >
</div >
```

if your handling everything on the same page dont put action